# Why do my buttons look like this? (unity game development)

Tags: unity, c#

They are extremely ugly? I can't figure out why.

[image]

Comment: Looks pretty normal. What do you mean by "They are extremely ugly"?

Comment: I can't even see the image, it is blocked by my proxy.

Comment: First of all, this is editor view, so in game they might look different, unless you are using "world location" setting. Next, you can always customize UI by changing different settings on it, like text size for Text object of button.

Comment: It looks exactly the same in game.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the inspector settings of the "Play" text object, the button object and any parent objects when they have.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure but I do have two ideas for you to try:

1. Increase the texture resolution to make it more sharp.
2. It doesn't look to be using distance fields, just regular bi-linear filtering. Read about [Distance fields](https://www.google.pl/search?client=opera&q=unity%20distance%20fields&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8), which is one of the best ways to render sharp text, maybe this will help.

Comment: It in fact looks like the buttons are using the default Unity fonts, which as far as I have been told, are very low quality, and only really suitable for prototyping. A higher quality font would be needed for suitable readability.

Answer (score 0):

It's scene view in 3D. Look at "game" window in Unity or open, if you closed it.
You can also click "2D" in scene window.
Here:
[image: How to open Game window in Unity / change view]

Comment: That's not the problem. The buttons like like this even in game.

Answer (score 0):

You should edit your **Import Settings** fields to fit the image to your desires (this is done by clicking on the texture in the **Project Browser** window):

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ImportSettings.html

By changing **Wrap Mode** to **Clamp**, **Filter Mode** to **Point**, and setting the highest possible resolution in the **Max Size** list, and setting the **Format** to **Truecolor**.

Something like this should be enough:

[image: settings]

Just click **Apply** and that's all!

Good luck!